# How to type match/fold function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried for some time now to write the correct types for a match/fold function. Hope someone can help me get an Idea what I'm doing wrong.

The function should be generic, but consider you have the following union type as example.

```
class Square {
  type = "Square" as const
  constructor(public side: number) {}
}
class Circle {
  type = "Circle" as const
  constructor(public radius: number) {}
}
class Rectangle {
  type = "Rectangle" as const
  constructor(public width: number, public height: number) {}
}

type Shape = Square | Circle | Rectangle
```

I'm looking to have a match function so that I can handle all the Options and have type-safety for that. It kind of works with this solution.

```
type XMap<T, Key extends keyof T> = { [K in T[Key]]: T extends { type: K } ? T : never }

type XPattern<T, Key extends keyof T, R> = { [K in keyof XMap<T, Key>]: (shape: XMap<T, Key>[K]) => R }

function matcher<T, Key extends keyof T, R>(key: Key, pattern: XPattern<T, Key, R>): (shape: T) => R {
  return shape => pattern[shape[key]](shape as any)
}

const area = matcher<Shape, 'type', number>('type', {
  Square: square => square.side * square.side,
  Circle: circle => circle.radius * circle.radius * Math.PI,
  Rectangle: rect => rect.height * rect.width
})

const shapes = [new Circle(4.0), new Square(5.0), new Rectangle(6.0, 7.0)]

console.log(`Areas: ${shapes.map(area)}`)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCOBXMAnAptA3gWAFDWgBcBPABwwF5oAiBZda6SaYAewDsJC8C3PCUiYIVYoAFKUQAjEAEtg0CLIAmaAFzR2iALZS0KAJRYAvnlO5QkGAGFZKUBhz4iZSjVv2QaRsz5ceLBxcgsKiEtJyCihgyrKIEBpauvpGmObmllDQAEpowmDsAOZeWAEk5NBU1Ln5RV4+MH7czk0hIuKSMvLQAO4qhAAWiTp6KAA00J2R0ANosoUDhMPJhiZmeHjlGLADYBVUdKgYAD7QHg7QpzWEBcVoG7hb0AAaALJ7ADwAKhMA0mjEaBoAAehDQ7GUMAA1gDWAAzaBfAB8lSw0AA2r9oLJ2IjMQCALoEjRfIGg8GQtFbDRY4zQAD8iOgiTQADd9NBzJtXC8AApgQhglDsb5-AFksEQ6GwhE-HIoqiYDFYnHQGHEeEvd6kUXQf7EJHE6BiCC7cgaN6fOX6pGYglGCgo7Kch5wxDsYSyDjQbQC4CzFC6-USinSjWyibZJFidU0gETUgCoXsC38wX6EXW+PygwaE1m9SIh1O0rOdCERDCxQFyooxPp4Xo017NDo9VE-MtpgwArEAzrXB4JrVlswKjo9hoHpnOwOMQAFgAdAAGAwTSfTw7oMQAVhXa80U5yeRudTQYgAbCuJgB2fcEh7Do5gVG+wj+-QfHYtiYAci2v7riM+jRv+riAaWBBboWEBIEctaKHB6CLkoqjQAAVIh9BoChKhoGMATnF4GjALOJSOiwZE4dEsTxBhlGeNRMRxDAmHvIMi68gAkgRzjXLcxHQOgwgIcJhCLrM8yLPRYmLn0yiDGY-aDhYQSsF4i4gKwhRiAABgAgugkAaAAJJgzbkBAi6+qQYjPgYxi6cpQA)

As you can see in this Playground it still gives errors but somehow shows me the correct types in the matcher. Not sure how to correct this.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to get it to work. Note that I had to use different Types for the matching purposes:

```
type Shape = Square | Circle | Rectangle

/**
 * Given a type, a key on that type, and a potential value,
 * return if type is an object that extends { [key]: value }
 * 
 * Since union types distribute over conditionals (it tries one at a time),
 * this lets us start out with Shape and end up with a single of the three
 */
type XMatching<T, TKey extends keyof T, TValue> = T extends { [P in TKey]: TValue } 
  ? T 
  : never

type Test01 = XMatching<Shape, 'type', 'Circle'> // Circle
type Test02 = XMatching<Shape, 'type', 'Square' | 'Circle'> // Square | Circle
type Test03 = XMatching<Shape, 'type2', 'Square'> // ERR since `type2` is not a shared field
type Test04 = XMatching<Shape, 'type', 'Ellipse'> // never

/**
 * Given a type T, a key on that type TK, and another arbitrary type TR,
 * if type.key extends string (and therefore can be used as a key itself)
 * generate a map from all possible values of type.key to 
 * functions that take in the particular object with that particular value of type.key, e.g.
 * 
 * 'Circle' -> Circle
 * 'Square' -> Square
 * 
 * and returns the arbitrary type TR.
 * 
 * Otherwise, return never.
 * 
 * (there are certainly ways to write this without the conditional)
 */
type XPattern<T, TKey extends keyof T, TR> = T[TKey] extends string
  ? { [P in T[TKey]]: (matched: XMatching<T, TKey, P>) => TR }
  : never

function matcher<T, TKey extends keyof T, TR>(key: TKey, pattern: XPattern<T, TKey, TR>): (matched: T) => TR {
  return shape => pattern[shape[key]](shape)
}

const shapes = [new Circle(4.0), new Square(5.0), new Rectangle(6.0, 7.0)]

const area = matcher<Shape, 'type', number>('type', {
  Square: square => square.side * square.side,
  Circle: circle => circle.radius * circle.radius * Math.PI,
  Rectangle: rect => rect.height * rect.width
}) // OK!

const badArea01 = matcher<Shape, 'type', number>('type', {
  Square: square => square.side * square.side,
  Circle: circle => circle.radius * circle.radius * Math.PI,
  Rectangle: rect => rect.height * rect.width,
  Ellipse: ellipse => ellipse.radiusA * ellipse.radiusB * Math.PI 
}) // ERR since Ellipse has no match

const badArea02 = matcher<Shape, 'type', number>('type', {
  Square: square => square.side * square.side,
  Circle: circle => circle.radius * circle.radius * Math.PI,
  Rectangle: rect => "real big!" 
}) // ERR since returns a string, not a number
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works like a charm. Maybe one question, do you see a way to have some type inference? To not have to write all of it? probably not.